# get the part of element class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

i could have any of this examples:

```
<input type="text" class="some_class extra_1" />
<input type="text" class="some_class extra_4 some_class2" />
<textarea class="extra_17"></textarea>
```

I need to get the number after "extra_":

1, 4, 17

or complete class:

extra1, extra_4, extra_17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option:

```
var arr = $("input, textarea").map(function() {
    try {
        return /\s*extra_(\d+)\s*/.exec(this.className)[1];
    } catch (e) {
        return null;
    }
}).get();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nh7sv/

Comment: I used /\s*extra_(\d+)\s*/.exec(this.className)[1]; it's working fine, thank you

Comment: @mgalesic You are welcome! Another variant for regular expression is to change `\s*` to `\b` as follows: `/\bextra_(\d+)\b/`. It will also work.

Answer (score 2):

Like

```
var numbers = [ ];

$('input, textarea').each(function() {
    numbers = numbers.concat( this.className.split( /\s+/ ).filter(function( cl ) {
        return cl.indexOf( 'extra' ) === 0;
    }).map(function( cl ) {
        return +cl.split( '_' )[ 1 ];
    }) );
})

console.log( numbers ); // [1, 4, 17]
```

Comment: jup or you can use replace('extra_', '')

Comment: Isn't a filter needed to avoid exceptions ?

Answer (score 1):

To get the elements with the class beginning with extra_

To get the elements

```
$('[class^="extra_"]');
```

To get the full class

```
$('[class^="extra_"]').map(function(_, x) { return x.getAttribute('class'); });
```

To get the just the numbers

```
$('[class^="extra_"]').map(function(_, x) { 
  return parseInt(x.getAttribute('class').split('_')[1], 10); 
});
```

To get all elements containing extra_ in class and return the numbers :-

```
var t = $('[class*=extra_]').map(function() {
  return this.className.match(/extra_\d+/)[0].split('_')[1];
});

returns ["1", "42", "17"]
```

​

Comment: I don't think that's the question.

Comment: The attribute-starts-with selector doesn't check each individual class name, it checks the entire class attribute string `"some_class extra_4 some_class2"`; this approach only works for the `<textarea>`

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/LLeQF/

```
$('input, textarea').filter('[class*="extra_"]').each( function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('class').split('extra_')[1].split(' ')[0];
    alert( num );
});
```